# Extract string in regex

Tags: ruby, regex, string

im kinda new to Ruby but i have a question to regex in Ruby.

I have a String and i want to save the number in the string in a new variable and just the number.
ruby is a pink to blood-red colored gemstone, a variety8of the mineral corundum (aluminium oxide). 
My Text ist

```
ruby is a pink to blood-red colored gemstone, a variety8of the mineral corundum (aluminium oxide).
```

My regular expression is:

```
/blood-red colored gemstone, a variety(.*?)of the mineral corundum/m
```

Now i want to save the result in a new variable. So lets say:

```
var1 = 'ruby is a pink to blood-red colored gemstone, a variety8of the mineral corundum (aluminium oxide).'
```

and

```
var2 = var1[/blood-red colored gemstone, a variety(.*?)of the mineral corundum/m]
```

Now the result is the whole sentence from blood-red ... to ... mineral corundum.
but how can i get access to the middle without the borders. In Rubular it is shown as a "group" ( in my case i want access to the digit inside a sentence). How can i get access to this group?

You can watch my example here in Rubular http://rubular.com/r/PgAgwRw3a5

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-5B-5D):

> If a Regexp is supplied, the matching portion of the string is
>   returned. **If a capture follows the regular expression, which may be a
>   capture group index or name, follows the regular expression that
>   component of the MatchData is returned instead.**

So, this should work:

```
 var2 = var1[/blood-red colored gemstone, a variety(.*?)of the mineral corundum/m, 1]
 # => "8"
```

Comment: OMG. Perfect. This Community is sooo fast. Thanky you.
i assume the one means, that it should take the first character from the "result" string inside, right?

Comment: No, if you want a number, you would want to parse it: `var2.to_i` to receive `8`

Comment: Yes. I know that i have to convert it to an integer afterwards. But if i tested it, with more digits inside and the 1 in the regex give me then the whole string.

Comment: Yes, if you want the the outcome from `...variety18of...` would be `1`, you can either take the first character, _or_ change the expression to `... variety(.?).*of ...`

Comment: Hello, Uri--haven't seen you much of you lately.

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby each group is stored in a match. If you explicitly use [`String#match`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Regexp.html#method-i-match), a [`MatchData`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/MatchData.html) is returned and you can access the matches.

```
s = "ruby is a pink to blood-red colored gemstone, a variety8of the mineral corundum (aluminium oxide)."
r = /blood-red colored gemstone, a variety(.*?)of the mineral corundum/m

m = s.match(r)
m[1]
 => "8"
```

or

```
s.match(r)[1]
 => "8"
```

There are several shortcuts, more or less readable. For instance you can use `String#slice`.

```
s.slice(r, 1)
 => "8"
```

or the global variables

```
if s =~ m
  # $1 is the first match
  $1
end
```

If you are 100% sure the input is matched, then `slice` is a good option. If you need to perform some kind of test, then you may want to check that a match occurs.